# Database provisioning of a multi tenant application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi tenant application where the provisioning process will be automated.

The provisioning process will create a new SQL Server database with tables, procedures, functions and insert default data to the database.

My question is what is the best way to do this process?

Comment: You would like to create new database for new client on the fly? and wondering which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Would "by running an initialization TSQL script as an admin account, substituting the db-name" be too obvious an answer?

Comment: Try PowerShell, powertool to do this

Comment: @CuongLe by itself that isn't very illuminating...

Comment: I have just addded answer, pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too much headache trying to execute the database script from C# I decided to restore the database programmatically using the below script.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\BaackUpFile.bak'

RESTORE DATABASE DbName
FROM DISK = 'C:\BaackUpFile.bak'
WITH MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO 'C:\DataYourMDFFile.mdf',
MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO 'C:\DataYourLDFFile.ldf'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is:

```
1.Create multiple sets of SQL scripts like DBScripts,TableScripts,ProcScripts ect.
2.In DBScripts,just add create database code and here you can hardcode the db name also.
3.And whenver there are any changes in these scripts you can edit and release the new build for the client.

4.Client just has to click some button on front end to create DB,Tables,Sprocs etc.
```